# Pandas: Days left to a certain date

Tags: python, pandas

I expected to see an `int` with the number of days. However, I get to see `NaN`, `two rows` and `float64`. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
    >>> event_start_date = event_data['start_date'].loc[event_data['event_id'] == event_id]
    >>> last_order_date = event_orders['ds'].tail(1)
    >>> print(last_order_date)
    1493   2019-05-05 06:28:09.699094
    Name: ds, dtype: datetime64[ns]
    >>> print(event_start_date)
    0   2019-10-04 02:00:00
    Name: start_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
    >>> days_to_event = (event_start_date - last_order_date).dt.days
    >>> print(days_to_event)
    0      NaN
    1061   NaN
    dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is different index values, if subtract pandas try align index and because not match are created missing values.

Solution is create same index values e.g. by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
days_to_event = (event_start_date.reset_index(drop=True) - 
                 last_order_date.reset_index(drop=True)).dt.days
```

---

Or working with scalars - select first value by position by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
last_order_date = event_orders['ds'].tail(1)
```

change to:

```
last_order_date = event_orders['ds'].iat[0]
event_start_date = event_start_date.iat[0]

days_to_event = (event_start_date - last_order_date).days
```

Another idea is combination - subtract one item `Series` with scalar - output is one item `Series`:

```
last_order_date = event_orders['ds'].iat[0]
days_to_event = (event_start_date - last_order_date).dt.days
```